# How To Access The Value in HashTable

Tags: java, hashtable

I want to access the value in hashtable but in my code there is a exception . I want to access the constructor values of another class within the (KEY,VALUE) in the hastable this is the code of my class

```
public class StudentReg {   
    public String RegNo,Program ,FName;

    StudentReg(int Roll , String Program, String FName)
    {
        this.RegNo = " Fall2k14_ "  + Roll +  " " + Program;
        this.FName = FName;
        this.Program = Program;

    }
```

And Now i I have used a hashtable in which i want to access the values of the hastable using iterator this is the code of my main class And I have created a object T of hashtable and entered the key and the value set and get the values in the iterator

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Hashtable T = new Hashtable();

    T.put("Ahmed", new StudentReg(123,"BS(CS)","Murtaza"));
    T.put("Fahad", new StudentReg(456,"BE(EE)","...."));
    T.put("Alan", new StudentReg(769,"BBA","Rashee"));
    Set set =T.keySet(); // get set-view of keys
              // get iterator
    Iterator itr = set.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
       StudentReg  S3 = (StudentReg) itr.next();
       System.out.println(S3 + ": " +T.get(S3.RegNo+""+S3.Program+""+S3.FName));

 }
```

At this point System.out.println(S3 + ": " +T.get(S3.RegNo+""+S3.Program+""+S3.FName)); i want to access the values which has been passed in the constructor of StudentReg();
but i am unable to do that

Comment: Any point of using Bare Collections? Add <String,StudentReg> so that you will avoid having to cast the iterator.

Comment: What kind of exception do you receive? Paste the exception message into your question.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: it is showing the address not the data Fahad: hashtable.StudentReg@15db9742
Alan: hashtable.StudentReg@6d06d69c
Ahmed: hashtable.StudentReg@7852e922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating on your keys which are Strings. If you want to iterate on all objects that are of the `StudentReg` class, you want to iterate on `values()`.

I strongly recommend to add type parameters to the collections. This way your code would not compile, and you would see right away what the problem is.

```
Hashtable<String, StudentReg> T
     = new Hashtable<String, StudentReg>();
```

or if using java 7 or newer

```
Hashtable<String, StudentReg> T = new Hashtable<>();
```

Then you can iterate on the `values()` using a foreach construct.

```
for (StudentReg s : T.values()) {
    System.out.println(T.RegNo + " " + T.Program + " " + T.FName));
}
```

Comment: Lewandoski its not working i have tried both . it is showing the same exception

Comment: Have you removed the line with the cast? You do not need it anymore.

Comment: Sure, but a for loop is better

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the String... the keyset returns all the keys, not values...
If you want the keys and values you can do like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hashtable<String, String> hashtable = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    hashtable.put("a", "1");
    hashtable.put("b", "2");
    for (Entry<String, String> tuple : hashtable.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(tuple.getKey(), tuple.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: @henriquedg89 i want to access the values with the key

Comment: but brother i want to access the values with help of the constructor

Comment: you have both, the value and key